# Irreducible representations of symmetric group over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: representation-theory

It is known that every irreducible representation of $S_n$ can be realized over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it true every irreducible decomposition of permutation representations of $S_n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the decomposition over $\mathbb{Q}$? Or is there any relation between them? I believe they may not be the same as $\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: They are the same (up to base change). See Fulton's *Young tableaux* or Alistair Savage's recent notes https://alistairsavage.ca/symfunc/notes/Savage-SymmetricFunctions.pdf for a proof.